# Bokeh 0.12.9 chart with CDSView and CustomJSFilter resulting in empty plot with catagorical data

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm plotting a bar chart by querying data from a database and then filtering it with a CustomJSFilter.  The code executes but plot is empty apart from axis labels.

If I amend the SQL query to filter to the same day in the JS filter the plot returns data.

I've replicated the error with the sample data in the code below.  If you run this you'll see no values are plotted.

If data is replaced with :

```
area = ['Chester','Liverpool', 'Birmingham']
date = ['2017-09-22','2017-09-22','2017-09-22']
roomsavailable = [10,20,15]
```

i.e. only including a single date then the plot works.

This tells me there is an issue with the CDSFilter or the CustomJSFilter.  It fails to work when there is duplicate data but works when the duplication is removed.

Is this a bug with Bokeh or is there something wrong with my code?

```
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.io import show, output_file
from bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, Label, LabelSet,CDSView, CustomJSFilter, Filter, IndexFilter
from bokeh.layouts import row
from bokeh.plotting import figure
from bokeh.palettes import Spectral9, Viridis256



area = ['Chester','Liverpool', 'Birmingham','Chester','Liverpool', 'Birmingham']
date = ['2017-09-01','2017-09-01','2017-09-01','2017-09-22','2017-09-22','2017-09-22']
roomsavailable = [10,20,15,12,14,18]

source = ColumnDataSource(
    data=dict(area=area, roomsavailable=roomsavailable, date=date))

max_room = int(20 * round(float(max(roomsavailable)) / 20))

custom_filter = CustomJSFilter(code = '''
var indices = [];
for (var i = 0; i <= source.data['date'].length; i++){
    if (source.data['date'][i] == '2017-09-22') {
        indices.push(i)
    }
}
return indices;
''')

view = CDSView(source=source, filters=[custom_filter])

f_area = list(set(area)) #Get a distinct list of areas for plotting


p = figure(y_range=f_area, x_range=(0, 30), plot_width=600, plot_height=550, toolbar_location=None,
           title="Chester Student Rooms Available as of")
p.hbar(y='area', left=0, right='roomsavailable', height=0.8,source=source,view=view)

p.ygrid.grid_line_color = None
p.xaxis.axis_label = "Available Rooms"
p.outline_line_color = None
show(row(p))
```

Comment: There are several issues with CDSView for which a [PR](https://github.com/bokeh/bokeh/pull/6967) is being reviewed/merged.